# Multiple Wordpress Sites, Same Database but Filtered Content

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, customization, multi-taxonomy-query

I have been given a task to create Wordpress sites which will share the same database but filter content based on the domain...

Basically we will be creating news portals across provinces/states. Content can be entered from any domain, but based on the domain and tags, only certain articles should be shown.

e.g.
`www.Country.com` - must show all content.
`www.StateOne.com` - must show general content and content specific to State One.
`www.StateTwo.com` - must show general content and content specific to State Two.
etc.

How can I accomplish this? My thinking is that I create a `selector` in wp_config.php which can be passed through with every query but I haven't done any WordPress programming.

Is this a possible solution or is there a plugin I can use that can accomplish this?

Comment: You haven't done any wordpress programming and are expected to solve this task? I don't know of any plugin that does directly that. Maybe you could use multisite and some plugins that cross-post between those sites

Comment: Yeah that isn't going to be possible with a single database, that's just not how WordPress works.  As Kero said, you will need to use multi-site and some cross-posting plugins to achieve the same effect.  You might have to do some customization to get things sent where you want them but that part shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: Thanks guys for your input. @kero I have this task because I did PHP. It would be too difficult for me to learn and develop plugins. My worry really was the DB side of things really. I also had the mind to rather develop it from scratch but my boss wanted me to check before I reinvent the wheel. Let me try creating it via multi-site and see if I can get the domains working. I think cross-posting would be tricky as not all post should be shared across all domains.